# "rules" is not allowed error with Webpack 4

Tags: angular, webpack-4

Recently I have updated my webpack 1 with webpack@4.39.1 where as per Webpack documentation module.loaders is replaced by module.rules and I'm using the same in webpack.config.js file but still I'm getting following error:
[1] "loaders" is required
[2] "rules" is not allowed

My webpack.config looks like this:

I have tried removing entire node_modules folder and fresh npm install so that old webpack is no longer available also I verified global node_modules but webpack is not installed globally.

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'ng-annotate-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          compact: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader?minimize=false'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules(\/|\\)globalize/,
        loader: 'imports?define=>false'
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules(\/|\\)cldrjs/,
        loader: 'imports?define=>false'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Please help me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Tony Ngo, I made my config file pattern same as your but still getting same error. My webpack version is 4.39.1

Comment: Can you add your package.json or upload your source code to github for me ?

Comment: @TonyNgo, Please see my project package.json as well as webpack config file here: https://github.com/mmmathur/AngularMigration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue by removing "webpack-validator" from my webpack.config.js file as it's no longer needed by webpack 4+

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "webpack": "^4.29.6" so you can compare with my config

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can view full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Comment: Matched my config file pattern with your config but still getting same error.
```

Comment: I'm matched my file pattern same as yours but still getting same error.